# Replacing multiple variables according to the index

Tags: replacement, group-theory, indexed-variable

I'm currently working on the Polya's Enumeration Theorem implementation in Mathematica. As an example, of what I want to do, here's a formula I'm working with:

$$P_{C_{12}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{12})=\frac{1}{12}\left(x^{12}_1+x^{6}_2+2x^{4}_3+2x^{3}_4+2x^{2}_6+4x^{1}_{12}\right)$$

I'd like to replace $x_i$ with another expression that involves $i$, $w^i+b^i$, and then simplify the whole expression. How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation depends on how you define your variables. I have used `x[i]` as an expression for $x_i$.

```
P = (1/12) (x[1]^12 + x[2]^6 + 2 x[3]^4 + 2 x[4]^3 + 2 x[6]^2 + 
    4 x[12]^1);

P2 = P /. x[i_] -> w^i + b^i
(* 1/12 ((b + w)^12 + (b^2 + w^2)^6 + 2 (b^3 + w^3)^4 + 
   2 (b^4 + w^4)^3 + 2 (b^6 + w^6)^2 + 4 (b^12 + w^12)) *)

P2 // Expand
(* b^12 + b^11 w + 6 b^10 w^2 + 19 b^9 w^3 + 43 b^8 w^4 + 66 b^7 w^5 + 
 80 b^6 w^6 + 66 b^5 w^7 + 43 b^4 w^8 + 19 b^3 w^9 + 6 b^2 w^10 + 
 b w^11 + w^12 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, is it possible to keep x's with subscripts and do something similar?

Comment: You mean like this? ``P = 1/12 (Subscript[x, 1]^12 + Subscript[x, 2]^6 + 2*Subscript[x, 3]^4 + 2*Subscript[x, 4]^3 + 2*Subscript[x, 6]^2 + 4*Subscript[x, 12]); P2 = P /. Subscript[x, i_] -> w^i + b^i``

Answer (score 1):

```
poly = CycleIndexPolynomial[CyclicGroup[12], Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, 12]];
Expand[poly /. Subscript[x, i_] -> w^i + b^i]
```

> b^12+b^11 w+6 b^10 w^2+19 b^9 w^3+43 b^8 w^4+66 b^7 w^5+80 b^6 w^6+66
> b^5 w^7+43 b^4 w^8+19 b^3 w^9+6 b^2 w^10+b w^11+w^12